# Using layout_weight for scrollviews

Tags: android, scrollview

I have threescroll views which should be placed adjacently. I gave weight 1 to each one. But they are not taking same areas. First one is taking 1/2 of total available space. Next two are taking the remaining half space equally. Here is the `xml` file. Where am I going wrong?

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/Ststus"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Search for Bluetooth devices" 
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

    </TableRow>

   <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

       <ScrollView
           android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="150dip"
           android:layout_weight="1">

           <TextView
               android:id="@+id/tv_mobile"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:gravity="center|center_vertical"
               android:text="Mobiles"
               android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
       </ScrollView>

        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/ScrollView02"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="150dip"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_laptops"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center|center_vertical"
                android:text="Computers"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        </ScrollView>

        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/ScrollView03"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="150dip"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_headset"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center|center_vertical"
                android:text="Headsets"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        </ScrollView>
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

Comment: Better to use LinearLayout instead of Table Layout..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change ScrollView's  `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` to `android:layout_width="0dip"`

Try this one

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/Ststus"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Search for Bluetooth devices" 
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

   <ScrollView
       android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
       android:layout_width="0dip"
       android:layout_height="150dip"
       android:layout_weight="1">

       <TextView
           android:id="@+id/tv_mobile"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:gravity="center|center_vertical"
           android:text="Mobiles"
           android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
   </ScrollView>

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/ScrollView02"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="150dip"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_laptops"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center|center_vertical"
            android:text="Computers"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    </ScrollView>

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/ScrollView03"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="150dip"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_headset"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center|center_vertical"
            android:text="Headsets"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    </ScrollView>
</TableRow>
```

Answer (score 0):

Layout weight mechanism only distributes *remaining* space after first layout pass. In the first layout pass, the scrollviews are `wrap_content` wide. Whatever is left of the table row horizontal space will be distributed in relation to weight.

Make the widths 0px to make them each take 1/3 of the space.

Answer (score 0):

I think that it will be good for You to use Linear-layout instead of Table-layout. Also Scroll-view Must contain a parent View Group to all of it's child. Text view isn't a View Group. Add Linear Layout OR Relative Layout as a parent to your text view which is inside Scroll View. Also set the layout_width to "0dp" for scrollView if you are assigning weight to it. See this for further reference http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html. Below is the sample code:-

```
<ScrollView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_above="@id/bnext"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_alignStart="@id/bnext" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:visibility="gone" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/Ststus"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Search for Bluetooth devices" 
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

</TableRow>
  <TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

   <ScrollView
       android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
       android:layout_width="0dp"
       android:layout_height="150dip"
       android:layout_weight="1">

       <TextView
           android:id="@+id/tv_mobile"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:gravity="center|center_vertical"
           android:text="Mobiles"
           android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
   </ScrollView>

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/ScrollView02"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="150dip"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_laptops"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center|center_vertical"
            android:text="Computers"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    </ScrollView>

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/ScrollView03"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="150dip"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_headset"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center|center_vertical"
            android:text="Headsets"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    </ScrollView>
</TableRow>

    </TableLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        <TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/Ststus"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:orientation="horizontal" >
<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Search for Bluetooth devices" 
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
</TableRow>
<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_mobile"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center|center_vertical"
            android:text="Mobiles"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
    </ScrollView>
    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/ScrollView02"
       android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"  >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_laptops"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center|center_vertical"
            android:text="Computers"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
    </ScrollView>
    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/ScrollView03"
       android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"  >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_headset"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center|center_vertical"
            android:text="Headsets"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
    </ScrollView>
</TableRow>
```